# Is "downfall" the same as rainfall or precipitation?

Tags: meaning, grammar

I have this sentence:

> The heavy downfall (rain and hail) last night caused severe damage to the surrounding area.

Does *downfall* mean the same as *rainfall* or *precipitation* in this context?

Comment: 'Precipitation' is in a very formal register. Neither it nor 'rainfall' really suggest a limited period of heavy rain, which 'downfall' does.

Comment: So, *downfall* can be used in this context?

Comment: _Downfall_ would apply better to human drama IMHO; in the UK _downpour_ would be a better term.

Comment: I'm talking US. Generally.

Comment: I'm a meteorologist by trade, and I would not use "downfall" in DeBedenHasen's example.  "Downpour" is associated with rain--liquid precipitation--not including hail.  I would use either "precipitation" or "rain and hail".  I might even recast the sentence "Last night's heavy rain and hail caused damage *in* [not *to*] the surrounding area."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at a [dictionary definition](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/downfall), *downfall* has the following meanings:

1. descent to a lower position or standing; overthrow; ruin.
2. something causing ruin, failure, etc.: *Liquor was his downfall.*
3. a fall, as of rain, snow, or the like, often sudden or heavy.

All usage examples are from news article headlines, which understandably favour the first two meanings. It is also well-known from the eponymous film about the end of Hitler's Third Reich.

In the same dictionary, *downpour* only has one meaning: "a heavy, drenching rain."

So while *downfall* can mean rain, *downpour* might be more obviously rain-related.

Comment: That's the one. So I won't have to change and re-submit the report to correct downfall. It isn't obvious but possible to use. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be understood, but it would be more natural to use either *rainfall* or *downpour*: *Last night's heavy downpour caused severe damage to the the surrounding area.*

Comment: Does "downpour" include not only rain but hail?  Reference?